# Why am I getting completely different voltage and power results from Simscape phasor simulation and load flow simulation?

Tags: power, simulation, simulink, system, power-flow-analysis

I am simulating the power system in the picture, with two generators and three PQ loads.
[image]

[image]

My problem is that when I try to simulate it in *Simscape*, the load flow analysis gives me completely different results than a regular phasor simulation where I measure the currents and voltages with the *Three-Phase V-I Measurement* blocks. Here are my simulation results:

[image: Phasor simulation results]

And here are the load flow results:
[image: Load flow results]

I am displaying Magnitude-Angle voltages and currents in *pu* in the phasor simulation, the load currents cause a voltage drop of around 0.2 *pu* and after removing the loads I get voltages of approximately 1 *pu* across the entire network. The load flow analysis however tells me the voltages are around 1 *pu* **with the loads** and calculates the powers according to the values I set in the *load flow* block settings; whereas when I try to calculate the powers at different buses from the values from the phasor simulation I get COMPLETELY different active and reactive power values and signs.

Do I understand it correctly that the *load flow* sections in the settings of the *Three-Phase Source* and *Three-Phase Series RLC Load* have no impact on the phasor simulation? Can I use the results from the phasor simulations at all if I have constant PQ blocks in the system which are seemingly ignored? Or am I just missing something?

I am new to *Simscape* and power systems in general and I got this massive assignment which requires me to handle all this so I would greatly appreciate any sort of help/advice. I would expect to get similar results from both approaches - load flow and phasor simulation. I went through the different block settings like 1000 times to check if I didn't mess anything up but everything seems to be in order.